# get model.tvalues instead of model.bse from statsmodels summary2

Tags: python, statsmodels, tvalue

I run a couple of regressions and I tabulate the results using summary2:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.iolib.summary2 import summary_col
mod1 = sm.OLS(df['y'], sm.add_constant(df['x']).fit()
mod2 = sm.OLS(df['y'], sm.add_constant(df['x','z']).fit()
spec1 = summary_col([mod1,mod2],stars=True)
print(spec1)
```

I get something like this

```
==================================
                   y         y    
----------------------------------
const          -1.8444   -0.9627  
               (3.8185)  (3.2661) 
x              -0.7539   -2.5027  
               (5.9229)  (5.0661) 
z                         19.9010**
                         (7.9656) 
R-squared      0.0195    0.0267   
R-squared Adj. 0.0035    0.0109   
==================================
```

The values in brackets are the standard errors of the OLS coefficients, for example `mod1.bse`. Instead, I would like to have the t statistics  `mod1.tvalues` instead. Is there a way to do this? I looked in the source code at https://tedboy.github.io/statsmodels_doc/_modules/statsmodels/iolib/summary2.html#summary_col, but could not understand how to achieve this.

Comment: The official statsmodels doc is here https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/index.html The tedboy docs look like a changed, old and outdated version.